# Animating HighChart by updating individual points

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I've replicated a HighCharts demo that shows a chart after a user clicks on a map at http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info, and am trying to modify it to update each point in the chart individually in order to animate it nicely.

The following code updates my series data based on the country clicked, or adds a series if the user has shift clicked to select multiple countries:

```
$.each(points, function (i) {

    if (countryChart.series[i]) {
        countryChart.series[i].update({
            name: this.name,
            data: countries[this.name].data,
        }, false, true);


        $.each(countryChart.series[i].data, function (j, point) {
            point.update(countries[countryChart.series[i].name].data[j], false);
        });

    } else {
        countryChart.addSeries({
            name: this.name,
            data: countries[this.name].data,
        }, false, true);

    }
});
```

Unfortunately the chart doesn't animate, it jumps into view.  I'd like to animate it by updating each point individually as per http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/point-update-column/

In place of:

```
countryChart.series[i].update({
    name: this.name,
    data: countries[this.name].data,
}, false, true);
```

I'm trying:

```
$.each(countryChart.series[i].data, function (j, point) {
    point.update(countries[countryChart.series[i].name].data[j], false);
});
```

but am getting an error of Cannot read property 'data' of undefined on the point.update line.

Comment: The problem is that you changed from `this.code3` to `this.name`. Any specific reason for that? Problem with updating and animation is in calling `series.update()` which will remove your nice animation. See demo without using `series.update()`: http://jsfiddle.net/925cd0mq/1/ And one more thing - your code assumes that you have always the same number of points (only `point.update()`) but I think that may vary. Consider adding/removing points using `series.addPoint()` and `point.remove()`.

Comment: Thanks for that - For my data set code3 and name are the same so I combined them.  My data will also always have the same amount of points